# Post processing GPS data with open source software

Tags: open-source-gis, gps

I am using Magellan Professional Mapper CX working on ArcPad 7.1 platform. It has sub-meter accuracy after post processing. Without post processing the data collected in the field is off by 10 to 15 feet.

Are there any open source software/Web applications that can post process the GPS data?

Comment: What are your typical post-processing uses? Open source software usually provides many small tools for different tasks. E.g. gpsbabel for conversion

Comment: To make the data more accurate is the only task I want to perform by doing post-processing using any free resources.

Answer (score 2):

On the site for the product it says the following under the [GPS Performance section](http://www.ashtech.com/mobilemapper-cx-2632.kjsp#GPS_performance):

- Go to the link above ------> Hit the "support tab" ---------> and the hit "GPS performance" (for some reason, my link doesn't lead directly to the page I was on)

Here's a copy/paste of what it says in that section:

**How accurate is MobileMapper CX?**

MobileMapper CX provides real-time, sub-meter accuracy through DGPS corrections. The optional MobileMapper Beacon receiver provides beacon corrections to MobileMapper CX via Bluetooth technology.

Note: Sub-meter performance is subject to satellite and environmental conditions. See the MobileMapper CX datasheet for details.

**Can I post-process MobileMapper CX data?**

Yes. Some data logging applications running on MobileMapper CX record GPS measurements that can be post-processed by MobileMapper Office.

**How do I set up the MobileMapper CX for real-time differential correction using SBAS (WAAS/EGNOS/MSAS) signals?**

Run the DGPS Configuration program (tap Start>Programs>GPS Utilities>DPGS Configuration > Select Mode > SBAS and tap OK. With the receiver set to None (autonomous mode), Beacon (MobileMapper Beacon) or Other RTCM Source, the MobileMapper CX will not use SBAS corrections even if it receives them.

**Where do I have to be in order to use SBAS corrections?**

You should use SBAS signals only if you are in North America or the Northern Pacific (WAAS), Europe (EGNOS) or Japan (MSAS). Although you may pick up SBAS signals outside of these areas, the corrections are calculated using ground stations only in these areas. The farther away from these areas your receiver is, the more error you may be introducing to your position calculations.

This information should be in your maunual .... no??

There's also information on integrating with arcpad at [this link](http://www.gsf.qc.ca/Gps/Magellan/MM6/MM6_En.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of this settings. I am actually looking for a software like this: http://www.kinematicgps.com/software.html

Answer (score 2):

Many tools are available, such as [GeoKettle](http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/)

However retelet was right: it all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to get your hands dirty then you might want to check out [GAMIT](http://www-gpsg.mit.edu/~simon/gtgk/).

> GAMIT, GLOBK, and TRACK form a comprehensive suite of programs for
>   analyzing GPS measurements primarily to study crustal deformation.