# Is there open source GPS post-processing software?

Tags: gps, rtklib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Processing GPS Data with open source software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/post-processing-gps-data-with-open-source-software)

Here at the office we have a couple of 15-year-old Trimble 4700 and 4800 units but now we don't have the software to do the post-processing. Trimble wants to sell a new license so we can continue making full use of this equipment.

Is there an open source alternative to GPS post-processing?

I found [GPSTk](http://www.gpstk.org/) and [RTKLIB](http://gpspp.sakura.ne.jp/rtklib/rtklib.htm) and I wanted to know whether someone has had some experience using these or other similar software.